# How to make app always running in background , so user alway get notifications even if the app is closed?

Tags: android, smooch

Hello what must I do to make my android app that integrates with smooch SDK always running in background.

example
If you have BBM, Facebook, or Gmail, when you close the app with back button or exit then the app will still send you a notification even though it is not running.

Comment: Use of GCM you can also retrive notification from web api by use of Alarm Manageer and broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The app is not running in background, but there is a `BroadcastReceiver` of the apps running in the background. Whenever the `BroadcastReceiver` receives a Notification, then it begins a `Service` which executes what needs to be done with the notification.
You can create the notifications on the server side with Google Cloud Messaging.

So, read about:

1. Google Cloud Messaging [Check it here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
2. Receiving the notification by `BroadcastReceiver`
3. Starting the `Service`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Smooch has GCM functionality built in. If you'd like to add GCM to your application, simply [follow this guide](http://docs.smooch.io/android/#configuring-push-notifications).